# Iterating over a specific range in a python string

Tags: python

Im having difficulty figuring out how to iterate over a string in python. My goal is to iterate up to a certain point in the string, and remove the rest of the elements after that iteration point and just work with the substring.

Lets say I have a string, say str1:`str1 = "8493 2020"`
And I have a number that specifies how far I want to iterate, say `a = 4`

How can I iterate over str1 up to a - and then remove all the characters after a?

I tried this but got a syntax error of "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable":

```
for i in str1(range(a)): 
    print i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over a slice.

```
>>> str1 = "8493 2020"
>>> a = 4
>>> for i in str1[:a]:
        print i


8
4
9
3
```

If you need to create a new string, just do.

```
>>> b = str1[:a]
>>> b
'8493'
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating up to the desired index:

```
>>> str1 = "8493 2020"
>>> a = 4
>>> for i in str1[:a]:
...     print i
...
8
4
9
3
```

Removing everything up to that index:

```
>>> str1 = str1[:a]
>>> str1
'8493'
```

Comment: This is almost identical to @SukritKalra's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'my string'
stop_idx = 3
print s[:stop_idx] # prints "my "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in str1:
   if i == a:
       x = str1[a+1:]
```

That will make a new string x without the unwanted parts of the string. Strings are immutable so you need to make a new one.